# replace value pandas one contitions from two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, conditional-statements

There must be a simple solution that I am not realizing. I need to take in considerations two columns of a dataframe to replace the NaN value in one of them. For this set I get the correct answer, but I need to make sure that both q1 is 0 and q2 is NaN before I replace the missing value of q2 not only that q1 is 0 that I have done here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'q1':[0,0,1,1,0,1], 'q2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 29, np.nan, 18]})
print df
  ID  q1  q2
0   1   0 NaN
1   2   0 NaN
2   3   1 NaN
3   4   1  29
4   5   0 NaN
5   6   1  18

df.loc[df.q1 ==0, 'q2']= 999
print df

ID  q1   q2
0   1   0  999
1   2   0  999
2   3   1  NaN
3   4   1   29
4   5   0  999
5   6   1   18
```

I have tried this, but it does not consider q2

```
df.loc[(df['q1'] == 0) & (df['q2']==np.nan), 'q2'] = 999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) for check `NaN`s:

```
df.loc[(df['q1'] == 0) & (df['q2'].isnull()), 'q2'] = 999
print (df)
   ID  q1     q2
0   1   0  999.0
1   2   0  999.0
2   3   1    NaN
3   4   1   29.0
4   5   0  999.0
5   6   1   18.0
```

---

For better testing some values was changed:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                  'q1':[0,0,1,1,0,1], 
                  'q2': [np.nan, 1.0, np.nan, 29, np.nan, 18]})

print (df)
   ID  q1    q2
0   1   0   NaN
1   2   0   1.0
2   3   1   NaN
3   4   1  29.0
4   5   0   NaN
5   6   1  18.0

df.loc[(df['q1'] == 0) & (df['q2'].isnull()), 'q2'] = 999
print (df)

   ID  q1     q2
0   1   0  999.0
1   2   0    1.0
2   3   1    NaN
3   4   1   29.0
4   5   0  999.0
5   6   1   18.0
```

Alternative solutions with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['q2'] = df['q2'].mask((df['q1'] == 0) & (df['q2'].isnull()), 999)
print (df)
   ID  q1     q2
0   1   0  999.0
1   2   0    1.0
2   3   1    NaN
3   4   1   29.0
4   5   0  999.0
5   6   1   18.0
```

---

```
df['q2'] = np.where((df['q1'] == 0) & (df['q2'].isnull()), 999,df['q2'])
print (df)
   ID  q1     q2
0   1   0  999.0
1   2   0    1.0
2   3   1    NaN
3   4   1   29.0
4   5   0  999.0
5   6   1   18.0
```